# Getting error in a python numpy and pandas when building a docker compose in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, numpy, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

I got the problem when I tried to build a docker-compose file in python. Whenever I try to build the docker file, I got the same problem repeatedly. I got another error that the pandas and numpy is not needed for the docker distribution. So, I deleted them from requirements.txt but stil got the same error.

```
Building ridesharingservice
    Step 1/8 : FROM python:3.8-alpine
     ---> 39cc898b3c31
    Step 2/8 : RUN mkdir /app
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 9417f7a1f210
    Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /app
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 6296aca1df76
    Step 4/8 : ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
     ---> Using cache
     ---> f68f8144c248
    Step 5/8 : RUN pip3 install -r /app/requirements.txt
     ---> Using cache
     ---> c69fc6c2021a
    Step 6/8 : ADD . /app
     ---> Using cache
     ---> d111d6a78517
    Step 7/8 : EXPOSE 8000
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 02dcb41e4513
    Step 8/8 : CMD ["python3" , "/app/ridesharing.py"]
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 39ea80e6901a
    Successfully built 39ea80e6901a
    Successfully tagged ridesharestep03_ridesharingservice:latest
    Building ratingservice
    Step 1/8 : FROM python:3.8-alpine
     ---> 39cc898b3c31
    Step 2/8 : RUN mkdir /app
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 9417f7a1f210
    Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /app
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 6296aca1df76
    Step 4/8 : ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
     ---> bb9ecaaad729
    Step 5/8 : RUN pip3 install -r /app/requirements.txt
     ---> Running in fdb7b8032d84
    Collecting bidict==0.21.2
      Downloading bidict-0.21.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
    Collecting click==7.1.2
      Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
    Collecting Flask==1.1.2
      Downloading Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
    Collecting flask-mysql-connector==1.1.0
      Downloading flask_mysql_connector-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
    Collecting Flask-SocketIO==5.0.1
      Downloading Flask_SocketIO-5.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
    Collecting itsdangerous==1.1.0
      Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
    Collecting Jinja2==2.11.3
      Downloading Jinja2-2.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
    Collecting MarkupSafe==1.1.1
      Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1.tar.gz (19 kB)
    Collecting mysql-connector-python==8.0.24
      Downloading mysql_connector_python-8.0.24-py2.py3-none-any.whl (319 kB)
    Collecting numpy==1.20.2
      Downloading numpy-1.20.2.zip (7.8 MB)
      Installing build dependencies: started
      Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
      Getting requirements to build wheel: started
      Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing wheel metadata: started
        Preparing wheel metadata: still running...
        Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpsxfkipa8
             cwd: /tmp/pip-install-6f2nu5fe/numpy_1e1ffb2c8d0f4670ae933987236dca34
        Complete output (226 lines):
        Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
        Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
        Cythonizing sources
        blas_opt_info:
        blas_mkl_info:
        customize UnixCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        blis_info:
          libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        openblas_info:
          libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        atlas_3_10_blas_info:
          libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        atlas_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        atlas_blas_info:
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        blas_info:
          libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        blas_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
        lapack_opt_info:
        lapack_mkl_info:
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        openblas_lapack_info:
          libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        openblas_clapack_info:
          libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        flame_info:
          libraries flame not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        atlas_3_10_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        atlas_3_10_info:
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        atlas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        atlas_info:
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        lapack_info:
          libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        lapack_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
          NOT AVAILABLE
        
        numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
          FOUND:
            language = c
            define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]
        
        running dist_info
        running build_src
        build_src
        building py_modules sources
        creating build
        creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8
        creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy
        creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/distutils
        building library "npymath" sources
        Could not locate executable gfortran
        Could not locate executable f95
        Could not locate executable ifort
        Could not locate executable ifc
        Could not locate executable lf95
        Could not locate executable pgfortran
        Could not locate executable nvfortran
        Could not locate executable f90
        Could not locate executable f77
        Could not locate executable fort
        Could not locate executable efort
        Could not locate executable efc
        Could not locate executable g77
        Could not locate executable g95
        Could not locate executable pathf95
        Could not locate executable nagfor
        Could not locate executable frt
        don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
        Running from numpy source directory.
        setup.py:485: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
          run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
        /tmp/pip-install-6f2nu5fe/numpy_1e1ffb2c8d0f4670ae933987236dca34/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
            Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
            Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
            A better performance should be easily gained by switching
            Blas library.
          if self._calc_info(blas):
        /tmp/pip-install-6f2nu5fe/numpy_1e1ffb2c8d0f4670ae933987236dca34/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
            the BLAS environment variable.
          if self._calc_info(blas):
        /tmp/pip-install-6f2nu5fe/numpy_1e1ffb2c8d0f4670ae933987236dca34/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
            
            
          atlas_3_10_threads_info:
          Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
            NOT AVAILABLE
      
          atlas_3_10_info:
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
            NOT AVAILABLE
      
          atlas_threads_info:
          Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
            NOT AVAILABLE
      
          atlas_info:
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
            NOT AVAILABLE
      
          lapack_info:
          customize UnixCCompiler
            libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            NOT AVAILABLE
      
          /tmp/pip-install-ryihfklw/numpy_edc6962052c8492d98ad701223d36b6d/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
              Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
              Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
              numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
              the LAPACK environment variable.
            if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
          lapack_src_info:
            NOT AVAILABLE
      
          /tmp/pip-install-ryihfklw/numpy_edc6962052c8492d98ad701223d36b6d/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
              Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
              Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
              numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
              the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
            if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
            NOT AVAILABLE
      
          /usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
            warnings.warn(msg)
          running install
          running build
          running config_cc
          unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
          running config_fc
          unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
          running build_src
          build_src
          building py_modules sources
          building library "npymath" sources
          get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu95', 'intel', 'lahey', 'pg', 'absoft', 'nag', 'vast', 'compaq', 'intele', 'intelem', 'gnu', 'g95', 'pathf95', 'nagfor']'
          customize Gnu95FCompiler
          Could not locate executable gfortran
          Could not locate executable f95
          customize IntelFCompiler
          Could not locate executable ifort
          Could not locate executable ifc
          customize LaheyFCompiler
          Could not locate executable lf95
          customize PGroupFCompiler
          Could not locate executable pgfortran
          customize AbsoftFCompiler
          Could not locate executable f90
          Could not locate executable f77
          customize NAGFCompiler
          customize VastFCompiler
          customize CompaqFCompiler
          Could not locate executable fort
          customize IntelItaniumFCompiler
          Could not locate executable efort
          Could not locate executable efc
          customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
          customize GnuFCompiler
          Could not locate executable g77
          customize G95FCompiler
          Could not locate executable g95
          customize PathScaleFCompiler
          Could not locate executable pathf95
          customize NAGFORCompiler
          Could not locate executable nagfor
          don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
          C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC
      
          compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/local/include/python3.8 -c'
          gcc: _configtest.c
          failure.
          removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
            File "/tmp/pip-install-ryihfklw/numpy_edc6962052c8492d98ad701223d36b6d/setup.py", line 443, in <module>
              setup_package()
            File "/tmp/pip-install-ryihfklw/numpy_edc6962052c8492d98ad701223d36b6d/setup.py", line 435, in setup_package
              setup(**metadata)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-ryihfklw/numpy_edc6962052c8492d98ad701223d36b6d/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 171, in setup
              return old_setup(**new_attr)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
              return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
              dist.run_commands()
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
              self.run_command(cmd)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
              cmd_obj.run()
            File "/tmp/pip-install-ryihfklw/numpy_edc6962052c8492d98ad701223d36b6d/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 62, in run
              r = self.setuptools_run()
            File "/tmp/pip-install-ryihfklw/numpy_edc6962052c8492d98ad701223d36b6d/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run
              return distutils_install.run(self)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
              self.run_command('build')
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
              self.distribution.run_command(command)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
              cmd_obj.run()
            File "/tmp/pip-install-ryihfklw/numpy_edc6962052c8492d98ad701223d36b6d/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 47, in run
              old_build.run(self)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
              self.run_command(cmd_name)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
              self.distribution.run_command(command)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
              cmd_obj.run()
            File "/tmp/pip-install-ryihfklw/numpy_edc6962052c8492d98ad701223d36b6d/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 142, in run
              self.build_sources()
            File "/tmp/pip-install-ryihfklw/numpy_edc6962052c8492d98ad701223d36b6d/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 153, in build_sources
              self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-ryihfklw/numpy_edc6962052c8492d98ad701223d36b6d/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 286, in build_library_sources
              sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
            File "/tmp/pip-install-ryihfklw/numpy_edc6962052c8492d98ad701223d36b6d/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 369, in generate_sources
              source = func(extension, build_dir)
            File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 669, in get_mathlib_info
              raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
          RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
          ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ryihfklw/numpy_edc6962052c8492d98ad701223d36b6d/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ryihfklw/numpy_edc6962052c8492d98ad701223d36b6d/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-dr7jce4s/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-8rqd46yz/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-8rqd46yz/overlay/include/python3.8/numpy Check the logs for full command output.
      ----------------------------------------
    WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/78/e4/a935f1701fac697c6c5458f86968bec5d2b4cb66e7f738225216ebaa20b4/pandas-1.2.2.tar.gz#sha256=14ed84b463e9b84c8ff9308a79b04bf591ae3122a376ee0f62c68a1bd917a773 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/) (requires-python:>=3.7.1). Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-5wp41dku/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-8rqd46yz/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.16.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
      Downloading pandas-1.2.1.tar.gz (5.5 MB)
      Installing build dependencies: started
```